# Sharing Registry Space across Multiple WSO2 DSS Instances

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I deployed a Governance Registry, a master Data Services Server and a slave Data Services Server according this tutorial (Strategy B with JDBC):
http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances#CO_JDBC_Strategy_B

Now, how can I add my data services (.dbs files) to Data Services Servers from Governance Registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So now since you've the master and slave nodes, the initial data services have to be put into the master node at the standard data services deployment directory, which is at $SERVER_ROOT/repository/deployment/server/dataservices/. So after you have all the data services there, you can use the new deployment synchronizer tool that is shipped with DSS 2.6.0 (or any Carbon 3.2.0 based product). The deployment synchronizer can be used to conveniently sync the deployment artifacts between the registry and the file system.

So, in the master node, simply goto the deployment synchronizer tool in the main menu and check-in the data. And after you do that, from the slave nodes, you can simply check-out deployment artifacts, which will copy the data services to the file system and they will be deployed. For more information, read the section under "Deployment Synchronizer" [here](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.0/docs/deployment_guide.html).

Comment: Is there any way to use G-Reg instead of DSS in order to deploy new data?

Comment: Yeah, basically you don't have to use the DSS node to always sync with others. You can basically enable the automatic sync functionality in deployment synchronizer in the DSS nodes, and it will automatically sync with GREG to deploy the new data.